# Ogre Switchable Graphics

Tags: ogre

I have a problem with AMD switchable graphics. It seems like that every Ogre based application I run, run with the integrated Intel GPU, although .

I think the problem is that the function for the GPU are called from a at runtime loaded rendersystem DLL, but how do I fix this problem?

Comment: NVIDIA has something similar which is called "Optimus". In this case you can manually specify applications for which you want to use the dedicated GPU. I would assume that AMD has something similar, maybe in the "Catalyst" tool.

Comment: I already set in the AMD catalyst the GPU that the OGRE application should use the high performance GPU. I also tried a newer Version of OGRE, the 2.0 release cannidat, and a beta version of the AMD driver. Now it seems like that the OpenGL and the Direct3D9 rendersystem use the decidated GPU. Only the Direct3D11 rendersystem don't use the high performance GPU, the OGRE graphic options dialog, where I can choose which GPU should be used says even that only the Intel HD 3000 is available. Anyway, the Direct3D11 rendersystem is still experimental, so I fixed the problem(mostly)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the problem is fixed(mostly) in later versions of OGRE(I only tried 2.0 RC) and/or in later versions of the AMD GPU driver, but only for the Direct3D9 and the OpenGL rendersystems.

Because the Direct3D11 rendersystem is still experimental, it's the not too bad, the wiki says anyway that it should only be used if a feature which other rendersystems don't have needed is.